# How to wait the loading of an IFrame?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

This is my code:

```
elFrame = parentContainer.find('iframe');
elFrame.load(function () {
    elFrame.contents().find('body').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

I append the "iframe" to the parentContainer through string like so:

```
parentContainer.append('<iframe src='+link+'></iframe>');
```

and now I want to change the body of the iframe every time it is loaded.

That function is never invoked on my website. Where am I wrong?

Comment: onload event syntax like you use is deprecated (or will be) but it is not your issue here. Is elFrame returning expected element?

Comment: elFrame is showed correctly on browser, it is called. But I can't wait  the loading of it. I guess the problem is because I do somethings like  `parentContainer.append('<iframe src="'+link+'"></iframe>');`

Comment: I mean, after `elFrame = parentContainer.find('iframe');` what give you `console.log(elFrame);`, the iframe element or empty object? You should show more relevant code btw.

Comment: Appending iframe in this way is a very bad idea.

Comment: @markzzz exactly that is the problem. you append this iframe to parent container, but it will not get updated in JQuery-DOM reference. thus you cannot bind handlers to the iframe in $(document).ready(). you have to bind the handler after you appended iframe

Comment: @KamilT No, this way of adding iframe as nothing bad if done correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/jz7Vh/

Comment: @Vogel612  your are right: <<you have to bind the handler after you appended iframe>>

Comment: @roasted dig in. that is a question I only theoretically could answer when reading into jquery again... has been a while

Comment: @KamilT you could keep your answer, was not bad and for sure could explain OP's issue

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you are trying to acces the iframe elemnt before it is generated in html.
Try using:

```
$(function(){
    elFrame = parentContainer.find('iframe');
    elFrame.load(function () {
        elFrame.contents().find('body').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

The second guess is that the "parentContainer" is not right, making the iframe unreachable. How do you get it? What is it's value?

Comment: fixed with elFrame.on('load',function (), thank you! Even if I don't know why it works...

Comment: @markzzz do you call that after appending the iFrame? because that is the solution then.